# mixing auto_increment and non in mySQL

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, import-from-excel

I have a set of tables where each table's ID key is auto_incrementing. Now my users want to import a bunch of external data that has different keys from a single csv flat file.

I think the best way to do it is to lock the tables, grab the next value for the auto_increment column for each table, then for each row I insert just swap out the existing primary key for the new AI value. This is going to get really ugly since the data to import has multiple tables and multiple key relationships.

Any other ideas on how to handle a problem like this? Stored procedure maybe? Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Is this something that you expect could happen again? and again? and again?
If yes, you probably better write a stored procedure which takes care of writing your data (from the CSV file) to the table(s) used in your system. This way you centralize any logic needed to create records and properly connect them through foreign keys (your DB could evolve while the CSV will remain static, or both change in different ways).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new field to the table you want to import into called old_key, import the csvs into temporary tables and then do something like

```
insert into mytable(firstname, lastname, old_key) 
select fname, lname, old_key from temp_table
```

The mytable_id field that is auto increment will work as normal and now you will have the old_key and a new mytable_id that you can use for mapping other foreign key relations. You can drop the temporary tables after the work is done